# How to include my software in the menu of Microsoft Office softwares (Word, Excel and PowerPoint)

Tags: ms-office

I would like to include a choice in Microsoft Office's context menu that will link to my software.

Briefly, what I would like to exactly do is this : the user selects a word, right click on it, then in the choices, the users click on my custom option. Then, it launches my application with the word as argument.

Exactly as Antidote does...for the ones that knows it.

Do anyone have any clue to achieve this? I have looked for it but I haven't find anything yet.

Comment: Although you might be able to do something like this in Microsoft's managed C++ this is something probably best done as an Office add-in. The easiest is probably some VBA which launches your executable with the word(s) as an argument(s). I can't see anything which relates this question to Qt. Alternatively you could write a simple C# app which uses the .Net Office libraries which come with Visual Studio.

Comment: At first it was related with qt because I made my application on QtCreator to make it on Windows and Mac, so I had in mind to make this for Office on Windows and (if it is possible) on Mac with the Office For Mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246837/How-to-add-a-menu-item-in-Microsoft-Office-Word-7) to execute whatever you'd like (your app, with an argument, perhaps?) Google came up with a lot of answers for me.

Other articles:

- [MSDN link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554969.aspx)
- [MSDN link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee691832.aspx)

Comment: Well, I was looking for using c++ to integrate it in my software...but I had not any clue of this...I'll check those links! thanks

Comment: Thanks, you help me a lot to understand how to do it. However, I find [here](http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/customize_shortcut_menu.html) how to do it really really easily. So thanks for pointing me in the right direction!!!

Comment: That's a pretty good link with nice example code. Hopefully it can help someone else in the future.